# How do I customize myLocationButton control in Google iOS SDK?

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

When I use Google maps sdk for ios. I can enable/disable myLocationButton=true/false and Google displays a recenter button in the bottom right automatically (attached). So how do I customize map recenter button as per light or dark theme? Since I don't have it's styling control and google is displaying it automatically?

[image]

Comment: Just scrolling through posts, do you still need help?

Comment: Yes. If possible please